# I am getting this no line found exception in server inputstream scanner

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, inputstream

I am building a small server-client programme and i am using scanner to scan inputstream. but it is getting no line found exception evrytime. i don't know what to do. please help... there is a line that server's output stream is passing to client.

here is a stack trace.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Scanner.java:1651)
    at Client.main(Client.java:26)
```

here is a code..

```
public class Client
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        final int SBAP_PORT = 100;
        try (Socket s = new Socket("localhost", SBAP_PORT))
        {
            InputStream instream = s.getInputStream();
            OutputStream outstream = s.getOutputStream();
            Scanner in = new Scanner(instream);
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(outstream);

            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
            String command = scanner.nextLine(); // client interact with server through here.

            while(!command.equalsIgnoreCase("QUIT")) {
                out.print(command+"\n");
                out.flush();
                String response = in.nextLine();  // i am getting error here.
                System.out.println(response);
                command = scanner.nextLine();
            }
            command = "QUIT";
            System.out.println(command);
            out.print(command);
            out.flush();
        }
    }
}
```

this is how server sends response to client.

```
if(command.equalsIgnoreCase("track"))
        {
            data = new ServerData(phrase);
            Thread t = new Thread(data);
            t.start();
            usr.addPortfolio(data.getTicker(), data.getPrice());
            out.print("OK!");
            out.flush();
        }
```

"out" is socket outputstream.

Comment: i am running in intelij IDE

Comment: How is your client sending data? This is one half of the client-server code.

Comment: I apologize; I misread the error location. It would appear perhaps your socket on the other end isn't actually open. Thus, as @ElliottFrisch mentioned, can we see the server side? Or have you tried with a trivial third-party program, like `nc`?

Comment: i have edited the question with server side actions

Comment: You use `out.print("OK!");`, so there is no new line character, which is what `Scanner.nextLine()` is waiting for. Switch to `out.println("OK!");` or `out.print("OK!\n");` instead.

Comment: problem remains the same

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: windows 10 2019

Comment: It would appear the issue still involves the socket from the server side. Unfortunately, there's no `nc` native to Windows, but my best advice going forward is still to test the server first. There are ported versions of netcat for windows, which you could use to directly send and receive data with the server. Or, if you have another program that does something similar, try it - just send and receive simple network data to make sure the server is sending valid data with new lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is likely because the server response does not have any line breaks. I would rewrite the way you process the data coming back from the socket by just reading it byte by byte instead.

```
public class Client
{
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{
    final int SBAP_PORT = 8080;
    try (Socket s = new Socket("localhost", SBAP_PORT))
    {
        InputStream instream = s.getInputStream();
        OutputStream outstream = s.getOutputStream();

        //Scanner in = new Scanner(instream);
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(outstream);

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String command = scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Command: " + command); 


        while(!command.equalsIgnoreCase("QUIT")) {
            out.print(command+"\n");
            out.flush();
            //String response = in.nextLine();  // i am getting error here.
            int i = 0;
            char c;    
            while(( i = instream.read())!=-1) {

                // converts integer to character
                c = (char)i;

                // prints character
                System.out.print(c);
            }



            command = scanner.nextLine();
        }
        command = "QUIT";
        System.out.println(command);
        out.print(command);
        out.flush();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: ya but even reading by bytes I am still getting an exception "No line Found"

Comment: You need to remove this line in your original code ---->  String response = in.nextLine();  // i am getting error here.

Comment: then how a client will know the response of the server?

Comment: That's what this line does----->   System.out.print(c);